# Wallaby and prototype error

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, wallaby.js

The thing is that prototype is not defined , although in the node console writing http.IncomingMessage.prototype does give an object as an output. Any Ideas ?

```
var req = Object.create(http.IncomingMessage.prototype)


Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
at http://localhost:62625/____wallaby-bundle.js?1501265946287&wallabyFileId=bundle:219253
```

Comment: It can't read the prototype property because the `http.IncomingMessage` object doesn't exist. I presume there is an asynchronous call somewhere before this and eventually `http.IncomingMessage` will exist, but at the moment you are trying to fiddle with it, it doesn't.

Comment: Agreeing with Will, `Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined` means that `http.IncomingMessage` is undefined.

Comment: how to fix that ?

Comment: Did you perhaps forget to require the `http` module?

Answer (score 10):

I think `http.IncomingMessage` is undefined.

It may happened http has been overridden some where in your code .

```
var http = require('http');
var req = Object.create(http.IncomingMessage.prototype)
```

I have tested the above code and it works.

Comment: I have the same issue: 
'''
var http = __webpack_require__(968);
var fresh = __webpack_require__(958);
var parseRange = __webpack_require__(961);
var parse = __webpack_require__(905);
var proxyaddr = __webpack_require__(964);

/**
 * Request prototype.
 * @public
 */

var req = Object.create(http.IncomingMessage.prototype

Comment: webpack bundle http module with id of `968`. Can you just check http module has been included in you webpack bundle.

Comment: Here is the bundle .js file. The http module seems to be included, but it still does not work :(

https://ufile.io/sot8h

Line 235912